# Consistent Type Error regarding converting a string to a float in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, floating-point, typeerror

I am working on an assignment for an Introduction to Programming course and would like some direction as to what I am missing and why I continue getting the same `TypeError`. I am able to assign my strings however when I try to convert them to a float I end with a `TypeError`.  I am pretty new to programming and coding in general so please don't be too harsh. I understand that it is probably something really obvious.

I have attempted to define the variable and convert it to a float from a string both prior to the calculation when I was setting up my inputs as well as during calculation of what the algorithm is attempting to execute.

```
enter_quizzes_weight = input("quizzes weight") 

enter_quizzes_average = input('quizzes average')


quizzes_grade = float(enter_quizzes_weight * enter_quizzes_average)
```

The expected result is supposed to be the output of converting the strings to floats and then multiplying `enter_quizzes_weight` and `enter_quiz_average`  however the actual result ends in the following error,

```
 "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'"
```

Comment: Like order-of-operations in math, things inside parentheses happen first.  You are trying to multiply `enter_quizzes_weight` and `enter_quizzes_average` _before_ converting to float.

Comment: It's better to turn the answers into floats in your first two lines and then `quizzes_grade` would be just the multiplication of both variables.

Comment: @JuanC I attempted that but I don't think I set it up correctly. I set it up as enter_quizzes_weight = input((float) quizzes weight) and I am getting a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0):

```
quizzes_grade = float(enter_quizzes_weight * enter_quizzes_average)
```

That code multiplies two variables and *then* converts the result to a float.

But you're doing the float conversion too late, because those two variables are strings, and you can't multiply strings.

You need to convert the variables to floats *before* multiplying:

```
quizzes_grade = float(enter_quizzes_weight) * float(enter_quizzes_average)
```

Comment: I attempted this line and I didn't get an error(which I feel is a step forward) but I also didn't get the desired output either despite setting my inputs up.

Comment: You'll have to explain what output you got, and why it wasn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

enter_quizzes_weight = float(input("quizzes weight"))

enter_quizzes_average = float(input('quizzes average'))

quizzes_grade = (enter_quizzes_weight * enter_quizzes_average)

You're turning the strings you get from `input("quizzes weight")`  and `input('quizzes average')` into floats, and then you multiply them